# AngularJS getting XML child node

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I am trying to parse XML using AngularJS and for that I use this here: https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml

This works great for XML with this format:

```
<parent>
  <child id="1" name="something" attribute="something-else"/>
</parent>
```

However, the XML that I'm trying to parse is in this format:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <grandchild1>Lorem</grandchild1>
    <grandchild2>Ipsum</grandchild2>
    <grandchild3>Dolor</grandchild3>
  </child>

  <child>
    <grandchild1>Lorem</grandchild1>
    <grandchild2>Ipsum</grandchild2>
    <grandchild3>Dolor</grandchild3>
  </child>
</parent>
```

My question is, how do I loop through each of the child nodes to get its respective grandchild nodes' properties?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator function:

```
function iterator(node)
  {
  var foo = node.nodeValue;
  return foo;
  }
```

along with a parser function:

```
function parser(node);
  {
  /* Transform childNodes into an array of values */
  var bar = Array.prototype.map.call(node.childNodes, iterator);
  return bar;
  }
```

along with a query function:

```
function xmlQuery(doc, node)
 {
 /* Aggregate matching nodes */
 var baz = doc.getElementsByTagName(node);
 return Array.prototype.map.call(baz, parser);
 }
```

and DOMParser:

```
function readXML(xmlfromajax)
 {
 /* get XML response as text */
 var xmlString = xmlfromajax;
 /* Parse XML and query */
 with (new DOMParser)
  {
  var xmlDOM = parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
  console.log(xmlDOM.documentElement.nodeName);
  return xmlQuery(xmlDOM, "child");
  }
 }
```

**References**

- [DOMParser's parseFromString function and IE 9](http://cggallant.blogspot.com/2011/03/domparsers-parsefromstring-function-and.html)
- [The tiny table sorter - or - you can write LINQ in JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/19/10442582.aspx)
- [JavaScript Array Extras in Detail](https://dev.opera.com/articles/javascript-array-extras-in-detail/)